# RegEx to get group of numbers or letters

Tags: json, regex

"text": "[\n  {\n    \"id\": \"059ffad4-1f6f-4221-82bb-1a56ca709e28\",\n    \"contentType\": \"tv\",\n    \"Logo\": null,\n    \"Large\": \"\",\n    \"Medium\": \"\",\n    \"Thumbnail\": \"https://imagesiwantnow.blob.core.windows.net/iwantnow/ott/episodes/2018-01-16/20141027-forevermore-289x163.jpg\",\n    \"title\": \"001 - Forevermore - Oct 27, 2014\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"id\": \"dfb35a01-865d-4203-a31c-ff97a6a1fa51\",\n    \"contentType\": \"tv\",\n    \"Logo\": null,\n    \"Large\": \"\",\n    \"Medium\": \"\",\n

is anybody can help me to resolve the regex.
I just want to get all the ID which is "059ffad4-1f6f-4221-82bb-1a56ca709e28" and "dfb35a01-865d-4203-a31c-ff97a6a1fa51"

I tried this: (d*\w*-\d*\w*-\d*\w*-\d*\w*-\d*\w*)
but the problem is it can only get one group

What I want is to get all the id and add them to listbox/textbox

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the programming language you use, you should use something else than regex to gather the `id` from the json data.

Nevertheless, your regex pattern works fine and matches all the IDs.

See: https://regex101.com/r/wShOlF/1